# Python: Dijkstra' algorithm

Tags: python, dijkstra

need a help with Dijkstra. I found a lot of codes on the internet, but I can't use any of them, because I'm not given a `graph`, but just lists of `Vertexes` & `Edges` into `createGraph` function. It's a homework and I gotta have some attributes in classes.
This is what I have:

```
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.minDistance = float('inf')
        self.previousVertex = None
        self.edges = []
        self.visited = False


class Edge:
    def __init__(self, source, target, weight):
        self.source = source
        self.target = target
        self.weight = weight


class Dijkstra:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertexes = []
        self.result = 0

    def createGraph(self, vertexes, edgesToVertexes):
        for i in range(len(vertexes)):
            self.vertexes.append(vertexes[i])
            for j in range(len(edgesToVertexes)):
                if edgesToVertexes[j].source == vertexes[i].id:
                    vertexes[i].edges.append(edgesToVertexes[j])

    def getVertexes(self):
        return self.vertexes

    def findMinID(self):
        maxDistance = 1000000
        curVertex = None
        result = None
        for i in range(len(self.vertexes)):
            self.vertexes[i] = curVertex
            if curVertex.visited is False and curVertex.minDistance < maxDistance:
                curVertex = result
                curVertex.minDistance = maxDistance
            else:
                pass
        self.result = result
        return

    def computePath(self, sourceId):
        start = None
        end = None
        road = None
        while start is None:
            if Vertex.id == sourceId:
                start = Vertex
                start.minDistance = 0
        start.visited = True
        for i in range(len(start.edges)):
            start.edges[i].target = end
            start.edges[i].weight = road
            if road < end.minDistance:
                end.minDistance = start.minDistance + road
                end.previousVertex = start.id
            else:
                pass
        self.findMinID()
        self.computePath(self.result.id)
```

I'm still beginner so I tried to keep it simple, but it's not working as it raises error:

> 'type' object is not subscriptable

or:

> AttributeError: type object 'Vertex' has no attribute 'id'

which makes absolutely no sense to me why.
I can use any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: For the purposes of learning computer science, you may find that implementing dikjstra without a Graph class will be more effective. After constructing an adjacency list, that can be done in ten lines. [See example](https://github.com/kipply/competitive-programming/blob/master/dmoj/sssp.py)

Comment: I know, but I have to do it like that, because that's the pattern I was given. I wouldn't do it like that either, but I have to.

Comment: Create a [mcve]. This looks like you want a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

When you put the line:

```
self.vertexes = Vertex
```

you are assigning the variable to the actual class. Probably what you wanted to do was make an empty list, as you `append` to it later:

```
self.vertexes = []
```

I would assume this is where the error comes from, as if you ever try to iterate over `self.vertexes`, you are iterating over the `Vertex` class, which is impossible and throws that error.

You also have later:

```
start = Vertex
```

Try initializing the start, like:

```
start = Vertex(sourceId, "vertex")
```

Also, the line before that you have

```
if Vertex.id == sourceId:
```

meaning that you might want to make the `id` variable in `Vertex` static:

```
class Vertex:
    id = 0
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        id += 1
```

Some suggestions: [class tutorial in python](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Classes_and_Objects)

Edit:

To find the vertex that has the id you want, use a filter:

```
start = None
for v in self.vertexes:
    if v.id == sourceId:
        start = Vertex(sourceId, v.name)
        start.minDistance = 0
        break
```

Comment: Yeah, I had that as a list the whole time, just tried that for printing. With the  `id` problem, I can't make a static variable baceause every object of `Vertex` class has its own unique `id`.

Comment: Then why do you access it statically?

Comment: That's where the second error is coming from by the way.

Comment: Ok, so how should I find a `Class` object with `id` = sourceID?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to change a name of a start `Vertex`, I have to work with given Vertexes and their `id` and `name`.